# Return All Rows In An Insert While Loop Within 1 Value Field

Tags: php, mysql

I have an insert:

```
$sql="INSERT into tasks(TITLE,DESCRIPTION) VALUES('$projectName',
'Description Documents: [url=http://myurl/$documentID/]$documentName[/url]')";
```

I have a query before it:

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ID, NAME, IBLOCK_ID FROM b_iblock_element WHERE IBLOCK_ID = '36' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 6");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
$documentID = $row['ID'];
$documentName = $row['NAME'];
}
```

This returns 6 IDs.  Now I want each of these ID's to form a URL in the INSERT.. So basically the description will return 6 links each linking to the relevant ID.

Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: Do you want to add all ids to one document in the description by just expanding the text or do you want to do something more intelligent?

Comment: All I'm wanting is the description field to show: Document Name 1, Document Name 2, Document Name 3, Document Name 4, Document Name 5, Document Name 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just build a String containing all the Urls, by concatenating them with e.g. implode(), then add this script to your description.

You also might have to add the NAME field to your select query, to be able to fetch it from the DB.

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ID, IBLOCK_ID FROM b_iblock_element WHERE IBLOCK_ID = '36' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 6");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
    $documentID = $row['ID'];
    $urls[] = "[url=http://myurl/$documentID/]" . $row["NAME"] . "[/url]";
}

$allUrls = implode(' ', $urls);

$sql="INSERT into tasks(TITLE,DESCRIPTION) VALUES('$projectName',
'Description Documents: " . $allUrls ."')";
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I need a line break between them but I think this is to do with my system running on BBCODE otherwise I would've included a <Br> tag where the ' ' is.  Thank you very much for your solution.